# How to control moving View over another View?

Tags: android, android-layout, gesturedetector

I managed to move red `LinearLayout` over another `LinearLayout` usign `TranslateAnimation`.

[image]

I indeed control start of animation, but not like in **YouTube** app or other similar apps as I have to wait until the animation finishes.

How can I gain more control over the movement of red `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @Luksprog It's not a duplicate. The other one should be closed. Vote there please.

Comment: If you need [`SilidingDrawer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) like features, animations won't do it, because there is not much to control like pause or reverse etc. You will have to implement your own touch listener.

Comment: @Singularity `SlidingDrawer` is not longer supported. And not in older SDKs, but as of SDK 17. What's the purpose of using it when it's not future-prone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set an animation listener over your animation, like this

```
       animationRed.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }
        });
```

Comment: welcome to SO :-) Please note that this site's code formatting software can't handle tabs gracefully.

Comment: This way you have to take care of each step. In absence of a better approach, this approach is DOABLE.